# Soloader in React Native

Tags: java, android

React native call Soloader.int() function in onCreate function in MainApplication.java.
What is the use of it?
what are the exact .so files that it loades?
Why solader is used as in its documentation it is mentioned that do not use it above API level 23?
What happens if we do not init Soloader.int() above API level > 23?
https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader

We tried to run application by removing Soloade.int() and it works fine.